Effect clarification for Fleece of the Dead God
In Cult of the Lamb, there’s a near endgame fleece called Fleece of the Dead God.
Its effect is:

When resurrecting, gain 2 Diseased Hearts

according to Fandom.
What exactly does the game mean by resurrecting? Does it refer to the Crown ability where you can sacrifice a follower if you die during a crusade to come back to life?
